# Altitude always 0. I cannot obtain the altitude above sea level

Tags: android, altitude

I get the altitude always 0. I want to obtain the altitude above sea level in Android using GPS.

My code is:

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    double lat = (double) (location.getLatitude());
    double lng = (double) (location.getLongitude());
    double alt = (double) (location.getAltitude());
    latitudine = (int) (lat * 1e6);
    longitudine = (int) (lng * 1e6);
    altitudine = (int) (alt * 1e6);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you check if this is device specific? Are you working in an emulator?

I would at first check, if your device supports the altitude determination with:

```
LocationManager locationManager; LocationProvider locationProvider;

/* Get LocationManager and LocationProvider for GPS */
locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
locationProvider = locationManager.getProvider(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

/* Check if GPS LocationProvider supports altitude */
locationProvider.supportsAltitude();
```

If you want to know if a location has a valid altitude set, use the following:

```
Location location;

/* Get current location from GPS */
location = Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

/* Check if the requested Location has its altitude set */
location.hasAltitude();
```

Comment: I have installed an altimeter app and works fine... so I suppose that the device supports altimeter function

Comment: however you haven't specified how initialize "locationProvider" variable

Comment: I'm sorry! Completed my answer above

Comment: @AndreaF did you ever find a solution for this? I have the same issue, my `onLocationChanged` returns either 0.0 or an incredibly high altitude (plus 80/90 meters) than the altimeter apps I installed on the same device.

Answer (score 2):

You should check whether the location contains altitude information: before calling `location.getAltitude()`, just call `location.hasAltitude()` to know if the returned location contains this type of information.

Depending on the location provider you use (NETWORK or GPS), it may not support altitude determination. If you have an application that works with altitude, try to find which location provider it is using.

If you want to check if a particular location provider supports altitude, first call `LocationManager.getProvider(SensorManager.GPS_PROVIDER)` to get the `LocationProvider` and then call the method `locationProvider.supportsAltitude()`.

Comment: I'm working in React + Capacitor app. I have the same problewm: altitude 0. Is ther any way to run the `.supportsAltitude()` in that environment?. Lat and Long are working well.